# Find + paste + find: do multiple queries to each file

Tags: files, find, imagemagick

I am trying to get for each file in a directory, a row with at least, the following fields (the order doesn't matter, although that one is the preferable):

```
 - Image resolution, in case it is an image. If not, just blank.
 - Modification date
 - Human readable file size
 - Filename
```

The files in the directory are jpg images and the rest just plain text files. I've tried with something like:

```
find . -type f -exec paste `identify {} 2> /dev/null` `ls -goh {}` \;
```

`ls` tells to me that `cannot access {}`. The `2> /dev/null` part inside `identify` is for skipping error messages for non-jpg files.

I've also tried with different combinations of `xargs` and `$()` and so on, but haven't found a way yet.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you just interested in the current directory's files? Or are you using `find` because you want the recursive search?

Comment: I'm actually not interested in a recursive search (because there is no subdirs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good use for an embedded `-exec` script:

```
find . -name \*.png -exec sh -c 'printf '%s,%s\\\\n' "$(identify -format '%hx%w' "$1")" "$(stat -c %y,%s,%n "$1")";' bash {} \; > out.csv
```

Sample output is:

```
32x32,2018-09-21 15:04:33.216773000 -0400,192,./favicon.png
20x20,2018-09-21 15:04:33.225771000 -0400,1202,./delete.png
```

Broken up for readability, that script is:

```
find . -name \*.png -exec sh -c 
  'printf '%s,%s\\\\n' 
     "$(identify -format '%hx%w' "$1")" 
     "$(stat -c %y,%s,%n "$1")";' 
  bash {} \; > out.csv
```

Note the extra quoting to get a single `\n` into `printf`.

Outside of `find`, to get such output for files in the current directory:

```
for f in ./*.png
do
  printf '%s,%s\n' "$(identify -format '%hx%w' "$f")" "$(stat -c %y,%s,%n "$f")"
done
```

Sample output is:

```
20x20,2018-09-21 15:04:33.225771000 -0400,1202,./delete.png
32x32,2018-09-21 15:04:33.216773000 -0400,192,./favicon.png
```

You can change the pieces out or add other pieces as needed; for 3rd command, just add another `%s` and quoted command.

I've generated a simplistic CSV-type output, but if your filenames might contain commas, you should quote the filename.  Ditto if you convert the file sizes from a simple byte string to one with commas in the thousands places.

Comment: You could do without `printf` here since both `identify` and `stat` can output  à la `printf` so e.g. `sh -c 'identify -format %hx%w, "$1"; stat -c %y,%s,%n "$1"'` will do.

Comment: I wanted to do that, @don, but my `identify` adds a newline to the output

Comment: ImageMagick 6.7.8-9

Comment: That's really odd... [There's an old bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=111126) but they say there it's fixed in 6.2.2 and later... Might as well report this upstream as this clearly should _not_ happen...

Comment: Seem to only add the newline at the end; when given multiple files, it adds it only the one at the end

Comment: can't find it, but https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/blob/9ddfcca575c623401d591c5effc245a924aaef1a/MagickCore/property.c#L3345 seems to be the area

Comment: I end up (before I saw your answer) using a simple `for`, precisely because I needed some type of variable to avoid parsing errors (like not substituting `{}` in my original naive use of `-exec`, as you do with `sh` + `$1`). Besides, I wanted the output is sorted by size (I forget to mention that in the question), so instead of piping `sort`  after the whole `find`, I just get a sorted view by `ls -S` in the `for` input (I think that way is a bit faster). Anyway, I've marked your solution as correct, because it is.

Answer (score 0):

The text in your substitutions is evaluated once before find even start. Note that the preferred way is now `$( )`. You can pass the commands quoted to a shell, but the easiest way is to just create a script and call the script from `find`.